# Should I exec() a client child process after accept()ing a new socket FD and fork()ing from the server?

Tags: c, linux, unix, network-programming

I am creating a server that listens for a connection from any device. After a connection is made and a client socket FD is created, I want to write all data transmitted by the device to a database. I am wondering if I should do all my work in the child process produced by fork or should I create a new process image through exec(). The client process will exist for as long as the device is transmitting data.

For example, should I do this:

```
//Main loop
while(1){
int newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, (socklen_t*)&addr_size);

//Create child process to handle the accepted connection
pid_t proc_id = fork();
if(proc_id == 0){

  close(server_fd);

  execvp("client", argv);

  }else{
    printf("Parent process, closing socket\n");
    close(new_fd);
  }
}
```

or should I continue executing from the if statement like so:

```
//Main loop
while(1){
int newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, (socklen_t*)&addr_size);

//Create child process to handle the accepted connection
pid_t proc_id = fork();
if(proc_id == 0){

  close(server_fd);

  /***Process data here***/

  }else{
    printf("Parent process, closing socket\n");
    close(newfd);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to exec a child after the fork if the code for the child is in the original process.  Indeed, you have to ensure that the child process knows which file descriptor to use, which is harder if you use an exec function than if you simply run the child code from the same executable.  There are multiple ways around "it iw harder", but you have to be cognizant of it.

Comment: Check up the select system call.